# Why does @Autowired work in my Controller but not in my Service?

Tags: java, spring, service, spring-mvc, autowired

In the `MyController`, `@Autowired` works fine to pull in `myService` without getters/setters:

```
@Controller
public class MyController
{
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;
```

But when I try to apply the `@Autowired` annotation to the `myOtherService` field of `MyService`, I get an error saying it can't find a necessary setter method for `myOtherService` -- but it works if I fill in the getter and setter methods for this field:

**THIS WORKS:**

```
@Service
public class MyService
{
    private MyOtherService myOtherService;

    public void setMyOtherService(MyOtherService myOtherService)
    {
        this.myOtherService = myOtherService;
    }

    public MyOtherService getMyOtherService()
    {
        return myOtherService;
    }
```

**THIS DOESN'T WORK:**

```
@Service
public class MyService
{
    @Autowired
    private MyOtherService myOtherService;
```

Does `@Autowired` only work on controllers?

Comment: Umm... there's no `@Autowired` in `MyService` in your example.

Comment: That's correct. What I'm showing above is the state it was in after I got it working by removing the `@Autowired` annotation and creating the appropriate getter and setter methods. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Show us what doesn't work, rather than what does.

Comment: How is your MyOtherService declared? Is package of MyOtherService in component-scan?

Comment: @padis: No, only the Controller package is in the component scan of the dispatcher servlet: `<context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.mycontrollers" />`. I don't 'declare' `MyOtherService` anywhere.

Comment: I meant what annotation(s) do you use in MyOtherService class?

Answer (score 3):

You gave your answer - you don't have `<context:component-scan />` for the service package. If you add it, you'll have annotation autowiring